# zsh - complex filename matching

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I have trouble passing a list of file names to a program when utilizing globbing operators.

Essentially the problem is that I have files with multi-stage suffixes and I want to match only the master files with the shorter suffix.

For example `filename.suffix_somedata` should be matched but `filename.suffix_somedata_extrainfo` should not.

I tried `ls filename.suffix_[a-zA-Z0-9]*` and `ls filename.suffix_[:alnum:]*`, but they do not work as I would expect.

Comment: Please clarify what the desired output is.  Do you want to see only the second file name (`filename.mainsuff_username`), because it's the only one that matches the pattern, or do you want to see all four filenames (or maybe just the last three), transformed somehow?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.  (BTW, some \*nix systems allow user names to contain non-alphanumeric characters, such as `-` and `_`.)

Comment: @G-Man I fail to see how putting an answered question on-hold makes sense, but OK.  I definitely do not understand the point of trying to find a hidden meaning in the question. The question is very straightforward.

Comment: Gee, how does it make sense to edit your question in response to a request to clarify what the desired output is, and still ***not show what the desired output is***?  You say that the question is very straightforward.  Well, it may be crystal clear in your mind, but we can’t read your mind.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You say that the question is answered.  Did you notice that the question got *two* answers, which did different things?  Obviously, the author of one of the answers misunderstood the question.  What sense does it make that *you* didn’t comment on the wrong answer, saying that it was wrong?  For what it’s worth, my primary understanding of the question was (apparently) correct — it aligned with your recent clarification — but I wasn’t sure enough to tell Baazigar that his answer was wrong, because I could see how he could have interpreted your question the way he did.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … What sense does it make for Super User not to delete your question now that it’s been answered? It makes sense if your question (and the correct answer) can benefit somebody else in the future. But they’re of no benefit if they’re ambiguous. (And that’s not even considering the fact that `filename.mainsuff_foo_bar` is ambiguous, because `foo_bar` could be a username, or `foo` could be a username.) Finally, don’t lay this all on my shoulders. Four people voted to close your question, and the other three are senior to me, with much higher reputations (and one of them is a ♦moderator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of the `*` regexp operator in `zsh -o extendedglob` is `#` (`##` for `+`). And you can also use ksh-style globbing with the `kshglob` option. So either:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
ls -d filename.mainsuff_[[:alnum:]]#
```

Or:

```
setopt kshglob
ls -d filename.mainsuff_*([[:alnum:]])(-)
```

(The `(-)` part is to prevent `([[:alnum:]])` from being taken as a glob qualifier (or you can do `setopt nobareglobqual`)).

Answer (score -2):

Here is one:

```
ls | cut -d '_' -f1,2
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for.